# When using image magick to process .gif,the smaller one still looks unsharpened,why?

Tags: imagemagick

Seems this issue doesn't exist for `.jpg` images, any reason for this?

Original:

[alt text http://internationalpropertiesregistry.com/Server/showFile.php?file=%2FUpload%2Fno_avatar_w150.gifb7f45ba30a4661e47bd0971fe2ac28ec.gif](http://internationalpropertiesregistry.com/Server/showFile.php?file=%2FUpload%2Fno_avatar_w150.gifb7f45ba30a4661e47bd0971fe2ac28ec.gif)

Output:

[alt text http://internationalpropertiesregistry.com/Server/showFile.php?file=%2FUpload%2Fno_avatar_w150.gif311186a22666b967caf26d072e091a6a.gif](http://internationalpropertiesregistry.com/Server/showFile.php?file=%2FUpload%2Fno_avatar_w150.gif311186a22666b967caf26d072e091a6a.gif)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that .gif supports only 1-bit alpha. If you open up those images in a paint program, you'll see that the larger one has a lot of white around the outside where the anti-aliasing is happening, but the smaller one has much of that anti-aliasing removed. It's not really the fault of ImageMagick, since there's not much it could do anyway.

I would suggest that .png is a better choice for these images instead of .gif. If you really must use .gif, then get rid of the alpha completely (it's not going to look nice on anything but a white background anyway).

Comment: What do you mean by **anti-aliasing** ?

Comment: @wamp: anti-aliasing is what makes the image look smooth. It generally doesn't work well with the 1-bit alpha that gif supports.

Comment: Why doesn't it work well? The issue doesn't happen with `jpg`

Comment: @wamp: It doesn't happen with jpg because jpg does not have an alpha channel at all. As I said, either remove the alpha mask from the original .gif file, or switch to a format that supports *full* alpha (such as .png).

Comment: Why is 1-bit alpha so special?

Comment: 1-bit means true of false, so a pixel is either transparent of not, antialiasing needs semi transparent pixels, so GIF can't handle this.. what you need is a technique called semi-flatten, but i think imagemagick doesnt support this out of the box, you need to implement it [link](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-semiflatten.html)